# How to fix the Jhipster aws subgenerator failing with "Unable to parse command line options: Unrecognized option: -ntp" error

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, maven, jhipster

I am running the Jhipster aws sub-generator like this:

jhipster aws

and I am getting the following error:

Error: Error: Command failed: ./mvnw -ntp verify -DskipTests=true -B -Pwar -Pprod
Unable to parse command line options: Unrecognized option: -ntp

Comment: What version of maven are you using?  `./mvnw -v` The `-ntp` flag was added in Maven 3.6.1

Comment: I am using version 3.3.3... how do I upgrade the to version 3.6.1 in the wrapper?

Answer (score 1):

The `-ntp` flag was added in Maven 3.6.1.  If you are using an older version of the Maven wrapper, you will have to update.  You can update it by running:

```
./mvnw -N io.takari:maven:0.7.6:wrapper -Dmaven=3.6.2
```